# ASP NET Core Serving specific html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I have this middleware:

```
public class SpecificPageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SpecificPageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (this.IsSubDomainRequest(context.Request.Host.Value)) 
        {
            if (this.IsIndexRequest(context.Request.Path.Value)) 
            {
                await this.ReturnIndexPage(context);
                return;
            }
        }

        await this.next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private bool IsSubDomainRequest(string host)
    {
        return host.StartsWith("subdomain")
                || host.Contains("subdomain");
    }

    private bool IsIndexRequest(string query)
    {
        return query == "/" || query == "/response.html";
    }

    private static async Task ReturnIndexPage(HttpContext context)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(@"wwwroot\response.html");
        byte[] buffer;
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Unable to find the requested file");
        }

        using (var stream = context.Response.Body)
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }

        context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    }
}
```

Quite simply, when I get something like this through: `subdomain.mydomain.com` I want to show a specific html page otherwise carry on the normal middleware pipeline to `www.mydomain.com`.

When this middleware gets hit, it ends up as a 404 in the browser. If I don't set a content type then it ends up as 200 with all the html written out as text, rather then rendered as html. What am I missing here?

I don't want to use `app.UseDefaultFiles()` or `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Comment: Did you try to use Fiddler2 to log the traffic? Maybe you have some invalid content before the headers are submitted

Comment: i will have a look, I did look at chrome network requests....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Answer.

One mistake you're making is here:

```
await this.ReturnIndexPage(context);                      // wrong!
await SpecificPageMiddleware.ReturnIndexPage(context);    // right (1)
await ReturnIndexPage(context);                           // right (2)
```

`this` means the instance. You cannot access a `static` method from the instance. Instead you have to qualify it with a type name (1) or with no qualification (2) and you're fine.

## Works on my machine

For good measure, [this is up on GitHub too as a demo.](https://github.com/bigfont/asp-net-core-vnow/tree/master/App04SimpleMiddleware)

**SimpleMiddleware.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace App04SimpleMiddleware
{
    public class SimpleMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public SimpleMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("simple"))
            {
                await ReturnIndexPage(context);          // right! 
                return;
            }
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

        private static async Task ReturnIndexPage(HttpContext context)
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(@"wwwroot\response.html");
            byte[] buffer;
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

                buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                buffer = Encoding.UTF8
                    .GetBytes("Unable to find the requested file");
            }

            context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

            using (var stream = context.Response.Body)
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

namespace App04SimpleMiddleware
{
    public class Startup
    {   
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<SimpleMiddleware>();            
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Simple query string]

[image: No query string]

Comment: Are you saying that what I've done works on your machine?

Comment: No. I am saying that my changed version does. More coming soon. :)

Comment: @CallumLinington Is your code building? I think you need to remove the `static` from your method.

Comment: that's the stupid resharper `ctrl + r + v` refactor to method.... I will look. I have `dnx-watch` on so I rarely look at it's output...

Comment: Oops. I mean that instead of `this.` you need to reference it via type name.

Comment: You were right about that static thing, resharper causing me pain... again!! thanks for that!

Comment: Setting `Response.ContentLength` after flushing stream to `Response.Body` may cause a System.InvalidOperationException (Headers are read-only, response has already started), should be reversed order (setting `Response.ContentLength` before the `using` statement).

Comment: @Marcus Thank you for that. Done.

Comment: I confirm that this works. This answer is pretty much useful! Thanks a lot!