# Add css file to an OWIN SelfHost

Tags: c#, owin

For my internship in `C#`, I've to create an embedded monitoring for existing applications, I wrote the whole "application" in an `Owin SelfHost` service to make it available and non dependant of the current architecture of these application, my server is launch with this snippet:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

    configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultRoute",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Monitoring", action = "Get" }
     );

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(configuration);
}

 WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9000");
```

I'm also providing a graphic interface for this monitoring, I'm using `HttpResponseMessage` to do this and simpmly write the `HTML` content with this code.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetGraphic()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent("...")
    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to add style to my current interface, I've put them in the same directory as the rest of the project (everything is stored in a subfolder of these others applications, called `Monitoring`) problem is that these file are not on the new hosted service, I can still access them with `projetUrl/Monitoring/file` but I would like to get them on `http://localhost:9000/file` because actually, this cause me `CORS` error when trying to load font file.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: You could try something along the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509588/asp-net-core-serving-specific-html-page you can create middleware to respond to certain requests. Alternatively, there maybe some `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used `UseStaticFiles()` to handle this situation, thanks Callumn Linington for the idea, I did not knew that something like this was existing!

Here's the code I used for potential future seeker:

```
appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    RequestPath = new PathString("/assets"),
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Monitoring/static"))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work...?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetStyle(string name)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = GetFileContent(name)
    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/css");
    return response;
}

private StringContent GetFileContent(string name)
{
    //TODO: fetch the file, read its contents
    return new StringContent(content);
}
```

Notice, that you can open a stream to read the files content in the `GetFileContents` method. You could even add some caching approach to that action method. Also, you can get creative and instead of taking one single string parameter, you can take an array of them and bundle the response

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write directly to the response stream?

Comment: @CallumLinington absolutely! But only if you're taking that answer as it is. There are many more things you can do here where writing directly to the response stream would make it impossible

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think that using static files is much easier!